# How to do a for loop with a promise?

Tags: web3js

Here is my contract code:

```
$.getJSON('Adoption.json', function(data) {
  // Get the necessary contract artifact file and instantiate it with truffle-contract
  var AdoptionArtifact = data;
  App.contracts.Adoption = TruffleContract(AdoptionArtifact);

  // Set the provider for our contract
  App.contracts.Adoption.setProvider(App.web3Provider);

  // Use our contract to retrieve and mark the adopted pets
  return App.markAdopted();
});
```

I use the contract by calling a method like the below

```
          var petsRow = $('#petsRow');
          var petTemplate = $('#petTemplate');

          petTemplate.remove("");


            App.contracts.Adoption.deployed().then(function(instance) {
              adoptionInstance = instance;
              // Execute adopt as a transaction

              for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
              {
                return adoptionInstance.getEntity(i);
              }

            }).then(function(result) {

            console.log(result);
             petTemplate.find('.panel-title').text(result[1]);
             petTemplate.find('img').attr('src', result[2]);
             petTemplate.find('.pet-breed').text();
             petTemplate.find('.pet-age').text();
             petTemplate.find('.pet-location').text();
             petTemplate.find('.price').text(result[3]);
             petTemplate.find('.price').attr('data-id', result[0]);

             //petTemplate.find('.panel-pet').eq(i).find('button').text('Sold').attr('disabled', true);
             petTemplate.find('.btn-adopt').attr('data-id', result[0]);

             petsRow.append(petTemplate.html());


          }).catch(function(err) {
            console.log(err.message);
          });
```

Problem I am having is when I try to create a for loop it doesn't work as it's async. Im trying to retreive each entity. It just returns the promise once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you shouldn't call `return` as you did. It's interrupting the loop. As I've understood, `adoptionInstance.getEntity(i)` returns a promise which you trying handle by a function in the last `then`. So i'm not really sure, but something like this should work:

`for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    adoptionInstance.getEntity(i).then(yourPromiseHandler).catch(function(err) { console.log(err.message);});
}`

As well `yourPromiseHandler` instead of your anonymous function